# Slots command in hostfile for mpirun not recognised

Tags: multiprocessing, mpi, intel-mpi

I saw another question that seemed similar [mpirun: token slots not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801970/mpirun-token-slots-not-supported) but their solution did not work for me.

I get the error
token slots not supported at this time
when running the command mpirun -hostfile temp.txt hostname

where temp.txt is

```
hostname1 slots=2
hostname2 slots=2
```

I have the mpirun version 2021.5
Release Date: 20211102 (id: 9279b7d62).

It did not work to instead write

```
hostname1:2
hostname2:2
```

in that case the command runs but it instead does the number of physical processors that are available, which is default.

EDIT: I am adding the full output

```
[host RAMSES]$ mpirun -hostfile temp.txt hostname
[mpiexec@host] HYD_hostfile_process_tokens (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/hostfile/hydra_hostfile.c:47): token slots not supported at this time
[mpiexec@host] HYD_hostfile_unique_parse (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/hostfile/hydra_hostfile.c:232): unable to process token
[mpiexec@host] match_arg (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/arg/hydra_arg.c:83): match handler returned error
[mpiexec@host] HYD_arg_parse_array (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/libhydra/arg/hydra_arg.c:128): argument matching returned error
[mpiexec@host] mpiexec_get_parameters (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/mpiexec_params.c:1359): error parsing input array
[mpiexec@host] main (../../../../../src/pm/i_hydra/mpiexec/mpiexec.c:1784): error parsing parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found that on my version of mpi I had to specify processor placement not in the hostfile, as most of the examples I found do, but rather in the machinefile.

So the new command and file look like:

```
mpirun -machinefile machine.txt hostname
```

machine.txt:

```
host1:2
host2:2
```